# How's the 'integer lattice' or the 'direct sum' of $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ not a Free group?

Tags: group-theory, lattice-orders, direct-sum, free-groups, free-abelian-group

My question is about the direct sum $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ which is a Free Abelian group and not a free group.

The the integer lattice, or what I think is the direct sum $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, is known as a Free Abelian group which can have basis such as $e_{1} = (1,0), e_{2} = (0,1)$. You can check exactly what I've read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group#Integers_and_lattices

The integers $\mathbb{Z}$ are a free group with one generator and thus are a free Abelian group, yet groups that comprise of two generators are not Abelian. And again you can check what I've read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group#Examples

Why is the integer lattice not also a free group with two generators $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ that is Abelian and with elements of the type $e_{1}^{4}e_{2}^{5}$ that equal elements such as $4e_{1}+5e_{2}$ of a Free Abelian group?

Comment: A free group with at least two generators are not abelian: $e_{1}e_{2} \neq e_{2}e_{1}$ in $F_2$. But a free abelian group is, as it says, abelian.

Comment: Because free groups with more than one generators are not commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free as in free groups means there are no relations. So a free group on two generators $a,b$ contains arbitrary words with the letters $a, b, a^{-1}, b^{-1}$ that do not contain $aa^{-1}, a^{-1}a, bb^{-1}, b^{-1}b$.

A free abelian group on $a,b$, however, always has the relation $ab=ba$, which is a relation not occurring in a free group. The two notions free and free abelian only coincide for free (abelian) groups with a single generator.

The concept of freeness comes from somewhere deeper: groups form a category. You can assign to a group its underlying bare set, that’s the forgetful functor. By definition, a free functor is a left adjoint to the forgetful functor, which for groups turns out to be the above construction. For abelian groups, however, the left adjoins to the (same) forgetful functor looks different; it’s precisely the free abelian group.

Answer (score 4):

In a group with a single generator, it is easy to see that this is abelian. A relation on such a group would be $a^n=1$ where $1$ is the identity, and such a relation renders the group finite.

In the case of two or more generators, the relation $xy=yx$ does not necessarily hold. If we wish to force it to hold we have to specify it as a relation in the definition of the group, and since it is not a trivial relation, the group which arises cannot be free - a free group is subject to no non-trivial relations.

A free abelian group is one whose only relations ensure that the generators commute (and hence that all the elements commute). The word "free" is still used, but it is a different idea. A free abelian group is "torsion free" because it has no elements except the identity of finite order.

Answer (score 0):

Not a free group due to commutativity.

Comment: The group $(\Bbb Z, +)$ is free and yet abelian.

Comment: The notions free and free abelian are the same for one generator only

Answer (score 0):

The presentation for $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ is $$\langle a,b\ |\ aba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle,$$
where the $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ term is there to guarantee commutativity. (It is, however, a free abelian group on two generators. But that's a definition thing.)

Comment: Okay then so if I don't utilise the relators I just don't model the group $(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}, +)$  on it?

Comment: No, Free Groups and Free Abelian Groups are completely different things. The only thing they have in common is the fact that a free group on one generator is the same as a free abelian group on one generator, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}$. Once you introduce more generators they become different things.